# How to develop left slide menu in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

How do I develop the above gif image using Unity3D?

Comment: Please give more information what you've already did to solve this problem. More information about [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us what you have tried? In your Question are important things missing please take a look at the link that @Florian posts.

Comment: Technically that is an animated transition and has nothing to do with 'gif's the answer I posted below should get you started but with no idea what you have tried yet it's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

the way is to use a GameObject who content all the panel inside a Canvas. translate this gameboject outside of the view and put an event on click to translate it inside the view.

you can use the `Transform.Translate();` solution to move the panel

Answer (score 0):

Make the game object or panel you want, and place it on the left with just the icon showing,

You will need:

```
bool isShowing=false;
```

The game object must have a collider on it, then you can add this method

```
 Public void  OnMouseDown(){
isShowing=!isShowing;
}
```

Them in update

```
  If(isShowing&&x<0){
Transform.translate(new Vector3(1,0,0);
} Else if (!isShowing&&x>(0-width){
Transform.translate(new Vector3(-1,0,0);
 }
```

This is pseudo but since you don't seem to have tried anything yet it should start you in the right direction. Let me know if u need clarification once you begin.